MATLAB pmtm Function Hangs Indefinitely for Certain EEG Data Files
I am working on an EEG emotion processing project using MATLAB and EEGLAB. My goal is to extract time-domain, frequency-domain, and wavelet-domain features from EEG data. While I have successfully extracted features from segmented data, I am facing issues when applying the pmtm function to compute the Power Spectral Density (PSD) on non-segmented data.
Problem Description
For certain EEG data files, the pmtm function hangs indefinitely, causing the script to become non-responsive. This happens even after detrending the data. The code processes some files without any issues, but for others, it gets stuck during the PSD computation.
Steps Taken
Detrending the Data: Changed from
[pxx, f] = pmtm(data, 4, [], EEG.srate);
to
[pxx, f] = pmtm(detrend(data), 4, [], EEG.srate);
which resolved the issue for some files but caused new issues with others.
Error Handling: Added error handling to log problematic files and bypass them.
Data Format: Attempted to process the data from scratch using .mat files instead of .set files, but the problem persisted.
Here is the relevant portion of my code with the timeout mechanism and error handling:
 for chan = 1:n_channels
    data = EEG.data(chan, :);
    % Frequency domain features
    for band = 1:n_bands
        try
            % Power Spectral Density using multitaper method
            [pxx, f] = pmtm(detrend(data), 4, [], EEG.srate);
            band_pxx = pxx(f >= freq_bands(band, 1) & f <= freq_bands(band, 2));
            
            if isempty(band_pxx)
                disp(['Warning: No data in frequency band ', band_names{band}, ' for channel ', num2str(chan)]);
                continue;
            end
            
            power_features(chan, band) = sum(band_pxx);
            std_features(chan, band) = std(band_pxx);
            entropy_features(chan, band) = wentropy(band_pxx, 'shannon');

            % Wavelet transform (using Morlet wavelet)
            scales = freq2scales(freq_bands(band, :), EEG.srate);
            wavelet_data = cwt(data, 'amor', EEG.srate, 'FrequencyLimits', freq_bands(band, :));
            wavelet_band_data = abs(wavelet_data);
            power_wavelet_features(chan, band) = sum(wavelet_band_data(:).^2);
            std_wavelet_features(chan, band) = std(wavelet_band_data(:));
            entropy_wavelet_features(chan, band) = wentropy(wavelet_band_data(:), 'shannon');
        catch ME
            disp(['Error processing channel ', num2str(chan), ' band ', band_names{band}, ': ', ME.message]);
            power_features(chan, band) = NaN;
            std_features(chan, band) = NaN;
            entropy_features(chan, band) = NaN;
            power_wavelet_features(chan, band) = NaN;
            std_wavelet_features(chan, band) = NaN;
            entropy_wavelet_features(chan, band) = NaN;
        end
    end
end

Questions

What could be causing the pmtm function to hang indefinitely for certain EEG data files?
How can I further debug or resolve this issue to ensure the pmtm function completes for all files?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

How big are the datasets affected? Can you split a failing one into two and identify which half the fault is in? Or output some progress tags as the computation progresses. You have to debug the pmtm code and figure out where it is getting stuck. A profiler may help with this since once stuck you should get a clear high water mark. Are there  any malformed numbers in the failing files?

There are two possible things that are happening, neither of which we can help with: (1) You're running out of memory, the OS starts swapping memory to disk like crazy, and it looks like MATLAB is doing nothing. Check your activity monitor or whatever it's called on your OS to see if this is happening. Usually the whole system slows down to a trickle. The solution is to process smaller arrays or buy more memory. (2) There's a bug in pmtm. Report the bug to MATLAB. Contact your MATLAB representative to see if it's a known bug and if there are workarounds.
